# Cycle detected error for @computed properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm just a beginner in MobX. I was trying out the computed properties in MobX and ran into this error

```
[mobx] Cycle detected in computation Store@1.values: function () {
  initializeInstance(this);
  return this[prop];
}
```

I created a store class with an observable computed property. When I tried to use it in a react functional component, it gave me this error. I saw a bunch of github issues that were opened for the same error message but they were all for very specific cases. I understood that it is because the value of the computed property is being accessed before it has been computed at least once. What I could not figure out is how to avoid this situation. I have made a very simple usecase in this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-volhard-42ly0?file=/src/App.js) where this error can be reproduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 class fields with the same name `values`, one is `observable`, another is `computed`, you can't use both of them and you actually don't need both of them.

```
export default class Store {
  @observable values; // <--- Not needed

  constructor() {
    this.selectedFilters = {};
    this.assetMap = {};
    this.searchResults = {};
  }

  @computed get values() {
    return [{}];
  }
}
```

`computed` is used to compute stuff (well, duh) or derive some values from another `observable`'s. For example, you could use it like that

```
export default class User {
  @observable name = 'John'; 
  @observable lastName= 'Doe'; 

  @computed get fullName() {
    return this.name + this.lastName
  }
}
```

Or in your case something like this could be useful

```
export default class Store {
  @observable values = []

  @computed get filteredValues() {
    return this.values.filter(someFilterFunction);
  }
}
```

More in the docs https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was under the impression that unless marked observable, changes to any propery(computed or otherwise) will not notified to the observer.